# trying to integrate google's recaptcha in node.js but server crashes if captcha is selected and submitted?

Tags: javascript, node.js

the server crashes once the recaptcha is selected

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Request.request [as _callback] (C:\recaptchav2                                                                                                                                  _node-master\server.js:29:17)
>       at self.callback (node                                                                                                                                  _modules\request\request.js:186:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\sesa481454\Documents\recaptchav2_node-ma                                                                                                                                  ster\node_modules\request\request.js:878:8)

```
app.post('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
  if(
    req.body.captcha === undefined ||
    req.body.captcha === '' ||
    req.body.captcha === null
  ){
    return res.json({"success": false, "msg":"Please select captcha"});
  }

  // Secret Key
  const secretKey = 'my secret key';

  // Verify URL
  const verifyUrl = `https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}&response=${req.body.captcha}&remoteip=${req.connection.remoteAddress}`;

  // Make Request To VerifyURL
  request(verifyUrl, (err, response, body) => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);//the console show error is caused from here
    console.log(body);

    // If Not Successful
    if(body.success !== undefined && !body.success){
      return res.json({"success": false, "msg":"Failed captcha verification"});
    }
    //If Successful
    return res.json({"success": true, "msg":"Captcha passed"});
  });
})
```

Comment: Maybe the request is throwing an error, can you add the line  `if (!err)  {  body = JSON.parse(body);//the console show error is caused from here
    console.log(body); }`

Comment: tried what you said got the following error >if(body.success !== undefined && !body.success){        success is undefined